# flutter returns Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get a percentage of a number. In some cases the numerator of the division operation could be zero.

I brought out a logical operation for this in flutter and it seems to be messing with my brain. It sometimes returns `Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt`. The problem is it gives me the expected result after hot reload, then when I reload again then the problem `Unsupported operation` comes again.

```
int? totalDriver = 0;
final totalCompleted = snapshot.data;//I got this from streamBuilder and everything is perfect here.
final percentage = ((totalCompleted! / totalDriver!) * 100).floor();//The starts from here. So I brought this logic.
if (percentage.isNaN || percentage.isInfinite) {
              return Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: screenWidth * 0.4,
                    child: Text(
                      "$completedString:",
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("$totalCompleted     (0%)"),
                ],
              );
            }eles {return...}
//I also later added this logic (So in case the denominator id 0, the percentage will be infinity, so if it's infinity it should return (0%))but it still persists.
if (totalDriver == 0) {
              return Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: screenWidth * 0.4,
                    child: Text(
                      "$completedString:",
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("$totalCompleted     (0%)"),
                ],
              );
            } eles {return...}
```

What might posible be the problem?

Comment: The error indicates that you called `.toInt()` on NaN or on infinity, but there is no `.toInt()` usage in the code that you've shown.  You do use `.floor()`, but `.toInt()` and `.floor()` are not the same and should generate different error messages.  Therefore your error probably comes from somewhere else (which is consistent with your `percentage.isNaN || percentage.isInfinite` check not helping).  Is there a stack trace?  Which line does it refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below code;

```
if (percentage.isNaN || percentage.isInfinite) {
              return Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: screenWidth * 0.4,
                    child: Text(
                      "$completedString:",
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("$totalCompleted     (0%)"),
                ],
              );
            }eles {return...}
```

Why? it's a redundant code.

You're checking if `totalDriver` is zero before performing the division operation. This ensures that the denominator of the division operation is never zero, which would result in `Infinity` or `NaN`. Therefore, the `isNaN` and `isInfinite` checks are not necessary because you're already handling the case where the denominator could be zero.

This is a modified code;

```
int? totalDriver = 0;
final totalCompleted = snapshot.data;

if (totalDriver == 0) {
 return Row(
   children: [
     SizedBox(
       width: screenWidth * 0.4,
       child: Text(
         "$completedString:",
         style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
       ),
     ),
     Text("$totalCompleted    (0%)"),
   ],
 );
} else {
 final percentage = ((totalCompleted! / totalDriver!) * 100).floor();
 // rest of your code
}
```

Here, if `totalDriver` is zero, the code will return a row with a text widget displaying **"0%"**. If `totalDriver` is not zero, the code will perform the division operation and calculate the percentage.

Comment: That didn't help. Actually I found a way of doing it. I will write as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if (totalDriver == 0) {
              return Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: screenWidth * 0.4,
                    child: Text(
                      "$completedString:",
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("$totalCancelled     (0%)"),
                ],
              );
            }
```

I did it this way and i got a good result

```
final totalCompleted = snapshot.data;
            int? percentage = 0;
            totalDriver == 0
                ? percentage = 0
                : percentage = ((totalCompleted! / totalDriver!) * 100).floor();
return Row(children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: screenWidth * 0.4,
                  child: Text(
                    "$completedString:",
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
                  ),
                ),
                Text("$totalCompleted     ($percentage%)"),
              ],
            );
```

In this case, whether the numerator or dinomenator is zero, the percentage is always zero since zero devided by any number is zero